# Using aperiodic monotiling for repeatable pseudorandom number generation

Tags: tiling, random-functions

As a caveat, i am not a mathematician but rather a programmer with an amateur interest in patterns, fractals, sequences, data science.

That said, i have been following recent developments in aperiodic tiling with interest.

I've had an idea for an application for it, but I don't know enough in the field of mathematics to know if:

1. It's obvious, been done, move on
2. It's an interesting idea worth exploring, or
3. It'll never work or be useful, just stop now.

The thought is as follows:

1. By definition, aperiodic monotiles don't repeat on the plane, therefore
2. They are effectively a visual representation of an infinite, non repeating sequence.
3. They can be computed relatively easily (e.g. see [here](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/%7Esgtatham/quasiblog/aperiodic-tilings/)), and the next tile can be calculated based on the position of the previous one.
4. Therefore, you effectively have a pseudorandom number sequence, given a seed of the coordinates to start at.

Is this worth exploring, or just a rabbit hole leading to a dead end?

Comment: It'll never work or be useful, just stop now. To understand why, consider the full implications of your third thought. If the first few tiles determine the entire pattern, then you can never get any more numbers out than there are different starting patterns. A good random number generator should be capable of producing a vast supply of different numbers. That said, I do not believe (3) is actually true - there are infinitely many places where choices can be made while generating the patterns. But even so, this is a much more complicated calculation than other methods.